# Neo4j and Cypher: find all reachable nodes from a set of nodes with some constraints

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph containing two kinds of nodes: user nodes and IP nodes.

The only edge I have is `:LOGGED_IN` from user node to IP node.

What I am trying to find is all reachable user nodes from one user node.

So I have a Cypher like this:

```
MATCH (u: User)-[*]-(connected: User) 
WHERE u.user_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
RETURN distinct u, connected
```

However, I found that some IP nodes could be potentially a proxy IP so there will be more than 100 `:LOGGED_IN` edges to that specific IP node.

I am looking for a way to find all reachable user nodes but bypass all the one in the path with a proxy IP.

Also the definition of proxy IP node should be configurable like I can set a threshold to 1000 `:LOGGED_IN` edges. If there are more than 1000 incoming edges to the IP than it's a proxy IP.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to Bruno's solution (in case you have a great meany proxy `ip` nodes), is to add a WHERE clause to exclude any of those proxy nodes during the expansion.

```
match p = (u:User)-[*]-(connected:User) 
where u.user_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
and none(node in nodes(p) where node:ip and size((node)<-[:LOGGED_IN]-()) >= 1000)
return distinct u, connected
```

The `none()` function will be evaluated during expansion, not in a filter after the expansion, which should work for you.

One other thing you could try is using the expansion procs from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), some of which are optimized for only finding distinct nodes instead of finding all possible paths to the same nodes.

```
match (u:User)
where u.user_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
call apoc.path.subgraphNodes(u, {labelFilter:'>User'}) yield node as connected
return u, connected
```

This one can't currently be optimized to exclude proxy ip nodes, but the NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness used during expansion may make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
match (i:ip)
where size(()-[:LOGGED_IN]->(i)) > 1000
match p = (u:User)-[*]-(connected:User) 
where u.user_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
and not i in nodes(p)
return distinct u, connected
```

That is: get all IP nodes with more than 1000 `:LOGGED_IN` relations. Then, get all paths that does not contains these nodes and return the desired data.

Comment: There can be multiple `i` nodes. Your current solution does not look for paths without all `i` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is another version of @BrunoPeres' query that is fixed to correctly find paths without any proxy nodes.

Also, Unlike @InverseFalcon's first query, this one checks the degree-ness of each `ip` node once, instead of checking the (label and) degree-ness of every node in every path. Which approach is better depends on your DB's data characteristics.

```
MATCH (i:ip)
WHERE SIZE(()-[:LOGGED_IN]->(i)) >= 1000
WITH COLLECT(i) AS proxies
MATCH path = (u:User)-[*]-(connected:User) 
WHERE u.user_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' AND NONE(p IN proxies WHERE p IN nodes(path))
RETURN DISTINCT u, connected
```

Comment: this works. However, there will be an issue when the proxy ip node has too many connected users said(~100000). My browser or Neo4j will just crash. Any way we can optimize the query?

Comment: Variable-length queries (like `()-[*}-()`) have exponential complexity. You can specify an upper bound on the variable-length query that will help to limit the time and space required. For example: `(u:User)-[*..5]-(connected:User)`